# Condition for redirecting to different page?

Tags: java, servlets

I wrote a servlet whose purpose is to login into the application only if the query executes...now what is the condition to be used for invalid username and id...I'm unable to write the condition..pls help me out...the servlet is...

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl ","scott","tiger");
            System.out.println("cnnection est");
        int Id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String Name=request.getParameter("firstname");
        boolean b=true;

        //Connection con =JdbcConnectionUtil.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from login where id=? and firstname=?");
        pst.setInt(1, Id);
        pst.setString(2, Name);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs!=null && rs.next())
        {

        //while(rs.next()){
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            System.out.println("here");
            pw.println("hello");
            pw.println(rs.getInt(1));
            pw.println(rs.getString(2));
            pw.println(rs.getString(3));

        }
        //}
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginFailed.html");

        }
//      


        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rd.forward` will solve the problem I think.

[How to forward requests from Servlet to JSP](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/how-to-forward-requests-from-servlet-t.html)

Comment: is this condition valid?? if(rs!=null && rs.next())

Comment: Yes, it is. It will check whether your resultset `rs` is null/empty or not. In the case when the `userid` and `firstname` will not match, the resultset `rs` will be empty and hence the condition will fail resulting in the statements in the else block to be executed.

Comment: @Anil: The `rs != null` check isn't useful. The `executeQuery()` method will never return a null result set.

Comment: @JBNizet: That will not be true in all the cases. Here, it is a possibility, but in other cases, the executeQuery can return an empty result set. An Example will be calling a SP using `CallableStatement`, which instead of returning any data just returns by executing the `return;` statement.

Comment: @Logan, but its not redirecting to loginfailed.html, if wrong entries are given...so i doubted my condition...

Comment: @Logan: An empty result set is a result set that returns false when next() is called. It's not the same as null. CallableSTatement inherits its executeQuery() method from PreparedStatement, and the javadoc of the method says: *Returns: a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the query; never null* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29

Comment: Add `rd.forward(req,res)` below the initialization of the RequestDispatcher.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for the help. Yes, I agree that the resultset will not be null in that case, rather it will an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

First you check for the correct parameters and then you do the logic. Also do not forget to close statements and connections to avoid memory leaks.

Here is refactored code:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //get parameters from request
    try {
        String idParam = request.getParameter("id");
        String name = request.getParameter("firstname");

        //check if request contains such parameters
        if (idParam == null || name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Id and Name parameters must not be null.");
        }

        //try casting idParam to int
        Integer id = null;
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(idParam);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw nfe;
        }

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl ", "scott", "tiger");

            pst = con.prepareStatement(
                    "select * from login where id=? and firstname=?");
            pst.setInt(1, id);
            pst.setString(2, name);

            //check if result returned any data
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                throw new Exception(
                        "No such user for id: " + id + " and name: " + name);
            }

            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.println("hello");
            pw.println(rs.getInt(1));
            pw.println(rs.getString(2));
            pw.println(rs.getString(3));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginFailed.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Something like that would be appropriate I think.